# How to get sort ordered using Unique filter in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a flag in a table. When I am trying to sort using Unique formula. It is not sorted as per my requirement.

Flag order needs to be

| Flag |
| --- |
| T1 |
| T2 |
| T10 |
| T11 |

instead of

| Flag |
| --- |
| T1 |
| T10 |
| T11 |
| T2 |
| T3 |

Below is my formula, I am also excluding DS and MS flag.

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(filter(A:A,A:A<>"DS",A:A<>"MS")))
```

Comment: Please consider checking under **Unique filter". J1 is Actual and K1 is expected.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/162guBnG2JBL3uuWuaSN_4xE-NAsGWGwV9ckyKDmmJn4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Edited the answer to match your expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort the flags primarily in alphabetic order by their alpha prefix, and secondarily in numeric order by the numbers that follow the alpha prefix, while omitting duplicate values and values where the prefix is `DS` or `MS`, and also omitting blanks, use this:

```
=query( 
  sortn( 
    A2:A, 
    9^9, 
    2, 
    iferror(regexextract(A2:A, "^[^\d]+"))
    & 
    iferror(text(value(regexextract(A2:A, "\d+")), "000000")), 
    true 
  ), 
  "where Col1 is not null 
   and not lower(Col1) matches '^(ds|ms)' 
   label Col1 'Flag' ", 
  0 
)
```

See cell `L2` in your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/162guBnG2JBL3uuWuaSN_4xE-NAsGWGwV9ckyKDmmJn4/edit#gid=942850477).

Comment: Amazing, Thanks. you are the best.